# Return days without hours in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My expected outcome is 77. However, with my current solution, I also get back `days 06:57:45.145166`. I tried to add `dt.days` to `difference`, but that didn't resolve it. What I am doing wrong here?

```
>>> today = pd.to_datetime('today')
>>> print(today)
2019-07-20 08:57:45.145166
>>> print(event_data['start_date'][0])
2019-09-04 02:00:00

>>> difference_in_days = today - event_data['start_date'][0]
>>> print(difference_in_days)
77 days 06:57:45.145166
```

Comment: difference_in_days.dt.days

Comment: I tried that but it says `AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Timedelta.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.days.html) if working with scalars:

```
difference_in_days = (today - event_data['start_date'][0]).days
```

If working with `Series` filled by timedeltas use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
(today - event_data['start_date']).days.dt.days
```

Comment: Ahh only using `.days` actually resolved it. I always read online it should be `dt.days`? But there I got back `AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Thank you jezrael!

Comment: @JoeyCoder - Because `dt.days` working with Series, like [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), if working with `DatetimeIndex` or scalars use `days`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by datatype:

```
difference_in_days = difference_in_days.days
```

Comment: @jezrael imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.